# Minesweeper confusion

Tags: minesweeper

I'm getting a bit confused about something I keep encountering when playing minesweeper. I keep seeing the following formation:
[image]

```
?????
?1x1?
?1x1?
?????
```

Surely those 1's should be 2's, as each one is adjacent to both of the mines in the centre? My initial thought was that this is a bug, but I've encountered it on multiple website versions of minesweeper. Am I missing something, or is this just a common shared bug?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The crossed-out mine at the top means "there was no mine here, but you incorrectly placed a flag". There is only one mine next to them, and it's the one highlighted in red; the other one is *not* actually a mine.

Comment: Right, that makes much more sense. Thanks!